# Simple Blutooth chat application By displaying the progressive dialog

Tags: android, bluetooth

Hi friends I am doing a simple Bluetooth chat application and I am unable to send the device name from one The BLE activity to another Alert Dialog Activity through intent. in next activity I have taken the name and displaying the details. 
   I have taken here async task to display the progressive dialog in that I have written the pairing devices code. Can any one help to solve this problem.
you'r help much need. Thnq:-)

I am getting this exception in the Async Task:

```
07-17 14:30:59.266: E/AndroidRuntime(3615): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-17 14:30:59.266: E/AndroidRuntime(3615): Process: com.appzoy.bluetoothlowenergyapplication, PID: 3615
07-17 14:30:59.266: E/AndroidRuntime(3615): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-17 14:30:59.266: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
07-17 14:30:59.266: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
07-17 14:30:59.266: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
07-17 14:30:59.266: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
07-17 14:30:59.266: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-17 14:30:59.266: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-17 14:30:59.266: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-17 14:30:59.266: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-17 14:30:59.266: E/AndroidRuntime(3615): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-17 14:30:59.266: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at com.appzoy.bluetoothlowenergyapplication.BLEChat$myAsyncTask.doInBackground(BLEChat.java:122)
07-17 14:30:59.266: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at com.appzoy.bluetoothlowenergyapplication.BLEChat$myAsyncTask.doInBackground(BLEChat.java:1)
07-17 14:30:59.266: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-17 14:30:59.266: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

I have the name as BLe but it is not a ble application only normal bluetooth application

```
                package com.appzoy.bluetoothlowenergyapplication;
                import java.util.ArrayList;
                import java.util.Set;
                import android.os.AsyncTask;
                import android.os.Bundle;
                import android.app.Activity;
                import android.app.ProgressDialog;
                import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
                import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
                import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
                import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
                import android.content.Context;
                import android.content.Intent;
                import android.content.IntentFilter;
                import android.graphics.Color;
                import android.util.Log;
                import android.view.View;
                import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
                import android.widget.Button;
                import android.widget.EditText;
                import android.widget.RadioButton;
                import android.widget.TextView;
                import android.widget.Toast;
                public class BLEChat extends Activity {
                  Button searching, send;
                  EditText devicelist,paircode;
                  private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
                  private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT=1;
                  ProgressDialog dialog;
                  private RadioButton changecolor;
                  TextView deviceadd;
                  Set<String> paired_devices;
                  ArrayList<String> Discovery_devices;

                  private boolean mScanning;


                  BluetoothManager bluetoothManager;

                    @Override
                    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_blechat);
                       searching = (Button) findViewById(R.id.finding);
                       send=(Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
                       devicelist=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.devicedetails);
                       paircode=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.paircode);
                       changecolor=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.display);
                       deviceadd=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.device_address);
                     Discovery_devices=new ArrayList<String>();
                      //searching of the bluetooth supportivity
                     bluetoothOperations();
                    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
                    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);


                   registerReceiver(bReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));        


                     //searching of the devices is happend through the background activity 
                      searching.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            new myAsyncTask().execute();
                //          if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                //              
                //              
                //          
                //              
                //          }else{
                //              
                //              Toast.makeText(BLEChat.this,"Tha application of bluetooth is stopped...      ", 2).show();
                //              bluetoothOperations();
                //          }


                        }

                    });



                    paircode.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                        }
                    });

                    }


                     private class Mytask extends AsyncTask<String,String, String> {
                            final String TAG = "BLEChat.Mytask";

                         protected void onPreExecute() {

                                Log.d(TAG,"executing inside of the preexecute method");
                                }

                         protected String doInBackground(String... params) {





                            return null; 



                            }
                            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


                            }


                     }   


                     class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>    {


                            @Override
                            protected void onPreExecute() {
                                Toast.makeText(BLEChat.this, "pre execute method", 1).show(); 
                                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(BLEChat.this, "",
                                        getString(R.string.progress_dialog), true, true);
                                super.onPreExecute();

                            }


                            @Override
                            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                                 Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

                                if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {

                                    for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                                         String str=device.getName();
                                        Intent in = new Intent(BLEChat.this, Alert_Dialog.class);
                                        in.putExtra("devicename",str);
                                        startActivity(in);
                                    }
                                    mScanning=true;

                                }
                                return null;
                            }

                            @Override
                            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                                Toast.makeText(BLEChat.this, "post execute method", 1).show(); 
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                if(mScanning=true){
                                    Intent in = new Intent(BLEChat.this, Alert_Dialog.class);

                                    startActivity(in);
                                }else{
                                    Toast.makeText(BLEChat.this, "NO devices are found", 1).show();      
                                }

                                super.onPostExecute(result);

                            }
                        }   


                    public void bluetoothOperations(){
                        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "The bluetooth device not supporting", 1).show();  
                        }
                    //checking wether it is enabled or not
                        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);

                        }else{
                              changecolor.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                        }


                    }

                    final BroadcastReceiver bReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

                        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                            String action = intent.getAction();

                            // When discovery finds a device

                            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {

                                 // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent

                                 BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                                 // add the name and the MAC address of the object to the arrayAdapter
         String str=device.getName()
                                 Intent in = new Intent(BLEChat.this, Alert_Dialog.class);
                                in.putExtra("devicename",str);
                                startActivity(in);

                            }

                        }

                    };







                    @Override
                    protected void onPause() {
                        super.onPause();

                        if(dialog != null)
                            dialog.dismiss();
                    }

                    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                        @Override
                        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                            final String action = intent.getAction();

                            if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
                                final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE,
                                                                     BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
                                switch (state) {
                                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                                    changecolor.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                                   Log.v("log", "this is shown");
                                   Toast.makeText(context, "bluetooth is off" , 2).show();
                                    break;
                                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                                    changecolor.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Turning Bluetooth off..." , 2).show();

                                    break;
                                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                                    changecolor.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Bluetooth on..." , 2).show();

                                    break;
                                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                                    changecolor.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Turning Bluetooth on..." , 2).show();

                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    };


                    @Override
                    public void onDestroy() {
                        super.onDestroy();

                        /* ... */

                        // Unregister broadcast listeners
                        this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
                        this.unregisterReceiver(bReceiver);
                    }
                }
```

This is the Custom Alert Dialog activity here i am taking the details from the above activity by bundle and then I am trying to display the details in the list view. can any one help please.

```
      package com.appzoy.bluetoothlowenergyapplication;

        import java.util.ArrayList;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.ListView;

        public class Alert_Dialog extends Activity {
        Button pair,cancel;
        ListView devicelist;
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayadapter;
        ArrayList<String> list;
            /** Called when the activity is first created. */
            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.alertdialog_file);
                pair=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPair);
                cancel=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
                devicelist=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.devicelistview);
                list=new ArrayList<String>();
                arrayadapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, list);
               devicelist.setAdapter(arrayadapter);
                pair.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("devicename");
                    list.add(data);
                    arrayadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }); 
                cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        finish();

                    }
                });

            }     

        }
```